# Datapower not capturing incoming Request

Tags: ibm-datapower

We will be getting multiple requests to an MPG service. But the issue is Suppose if we are receiving 4 requests only 3 requests are getting captured and sent to destination out of 4 requests. I checked in probe and it shows only 3 transaction requests. I checked the logs but nothing found. Seems it's missing to capture the 1st incoming request but not sure.  What could be the issue in capturing all the requests and how do I fix it ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1):

No, DataPower is not "missing" anything I'd say but the request you are missing is not hitting DataPower, or not hitting your service.
If something "hits" DataPower through a Front-side-handler (FSH) it will be in the logs, that is for certain!

You will need to check the client sending the requests for any errors and if none found there you will need to trace the network to figure out where the missing request is ending up.

Answer (score 0):

Capture Logs using LogTarget and enable prob and work with your network Team. I think this is related to network issue.